# Android - no view result returned from AsyncTask after modifying activity

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, imageview

I am trying to modify the activity below to make use of two AsyncTasks.  The original activity without the AsyncTasks worked and it resulted in a list of small thumbnail images shown in a vertical list of the listview.  But now after I click the button the view just goes blank.  As you can see in the onLoadClicked method, the lines I commented out were just a few and those have been relocated inside the onPostExecute methods of the respective AsyncTasks.  If you can help me understand what I over looked I would appreciate the help.  This is my first time trying to use an AsyncTask.  Also, I would like to later modify the activity future the make use of the onProgressUpdate method at least inside the downloadImagesTask so that the thumbnails would show up one by one as they are loaded instead of all at once at the end, but I am having trouble understanding how to fit in the publishProgress and onProgressUpdate into the current structure.  But fixing the current issue is more pressing for now.  But suggestions for further refinement along these lines would be helpful.  Thanks.

source code for main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private ImageAdapter adapter;
List<String> urls; // test1

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    this.adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

public void onLoadClicked(View view){
    // no need to trigger more than once
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // download the images and add them to the adapter
    //List<String> urls = downloadImageUrls(); // test1

    new DownloadImageUrlsTask().execute();
    if(urls != null){

        for(String url : urls){
            //Bitmap image = downloadImage(url); // test1
            new DownloadImageTask().execute(url);
            //adapter.addItem(image);
        }
    }
}

public List<String> downloadImageUrls(){
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://www.reddit.com/r/aww.json");
    AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("android");
    //DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try{
        final List<String> result = client.execute(get, new 
MyJsonResponseHandler());
        return result;
    }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        client.close();
    }
    return null;
}

private class DownloadImageUrlsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>>{
    @Override

    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void...voids){
        return downloadImageUrls();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result){
        urls = result;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

}

public Bitmap downloadImage(String url){
    try{

        URL u = new URL(url);
        InputStream is = u.openStream();
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        return b;
    }catch(MalformedURLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String...urls){
        return downloadImage(urls[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){
    //  ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    //  img.setImageBitmap(result);
        adapter.addItem(result);
    }


}

class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private List<Bitmap> images;
    private final Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context){
        super();
        this.context = context;
        images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    }

    public void updateImages(List<Bitmap> images){
        this.images = images;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return images != null ? images.size() : 0;
    }

    public Bitmap getItem(int position){
        return images != null ? images.get(position) : null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        final View view;
        if(convertView == null || !(convertView instanceof ImageView)){
            view = 
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.image_view, null);

        }else{
            view = convertView;
        }

        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) 
view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(getItem(position));

        return view;
    }

    public void addItem(Bitmap bitmap){
        images.add(bitmap);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}


static class MyJsonResponseHandler implements ResponseHandler<List<String>>{

    public List<String> handleResponse(HttpResponse response) throws 
ClientProtocolException, IOException{
        // Loop through the results and grab the thumbnail URLs
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray children = 
root.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("children");

            for(int i = 0; i < children.length(); i++){
                JSONObject result = children.getJSONObject(i);
                String thumb = 
result.getJSONObject("data").getString("thumbnail");
                results.add(thumb);

                // limit the results size to 6 in order to be nice 
to their servers
                if(results.size() >= 6) break;
            }
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return results;
    }
}


}
```

the source for the main.xml layout:

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<!-- <ImageView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/image"/> -->

<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Load Images"
    android:onClick="onLoadClicked"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

the source for the image_view.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/image"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

the source from the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.lesson11"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <!-- android:targetSdkVersion="17"  -->


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.lesson11.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: **"new DownloadImageUrlsTask().execute();"** - The call to `execute()` will return immediately as it's asynchronous (hence the name `AsyncTask`). That means the conditional check `if(urls != null)` is called immediately and the `AsyncTask` won't have completed what it's doing so `urls` will always be `null`.

Comment: Thanks!  I moved the section of code you pointed out into the onPostExecute method of the DownloadImageUrlsTask and it worked:
protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result){
   urls = result;
   if(urls != null){
    for(String url : urls){
     
     new DownloadImageTask().execute(url);
     
    }
   }
  }

Comment: Ps.  if you want credit for the answer please copy your note as an answer and I'll check it, otherwise I'll answer it and give you credit and direct people to your comment.

Comment: OK, I've expanded my comment out to be an answer. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the root of the problem...

```
new DownloadImageUrlsTask().execute();
if(urls != null){
    ...
}
```

The call to execute() will return immediately as it's asynchronous (hence the name AsyncTask).

The result is the conditional check in the code `if(urls != null)` is called immediately but the  `doInBackground(...)` method of the `AsyncTask` won't have completed what it's doing and `urls` will always be `null`.